# Query to find missing teacher-student combination

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a single table with two columns, TEACHER_ID and STUDENT_ID, which holds the data of all teachers teaching the students. One teacher can teach multiple students and one student can be taught by many teachers.

```
TEACHER_ID  STUDENT_ID
100         123    
100         124    
100         125    
100         126    
101         123    
101         124    
101         125    
102         123    
102         124    
102         125    
102         126    
103         123    
103         127
```

The need is to find which teacher is not teaching which student, i.e. it should show the output as the same 2 columns but the pair should be such that it doesn't exist in the table.

For example: student_id 127 is taught by teacher_id 103 alone, and similarly for all such missing pairs...

We can create a cross join to get all possible combinations and using the MINUS operator discard the actual data from the result leaving us with rest of the pairs.

But is there a better and efficient way to do this?

Comment: Are all students and all teachers guaranteed to be in the table? If not, do you have two other tables, e.g. TEACHERS and STUDENTS that are unique on TEACHER_ID and STUDENT_ID respectively?

Comment: yes this is the only table with lets say the only data in the table would be the one which I have provided.

Answer (score 2):

As for your question. You need to create all combinations first there isnt another way to find the missing pair.

**[SQL DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/2e588/8)**

```
With teachers as (
     SELECT DISTINCT "TEACHER_ID" 
     FROM Table1  
), students as (
     SELECT DISTINCT "STUDENT_ID"
     FROM Table1  
)  
SELECT teachers."TEACHER_ID" , students."STUDENT_ID"
FROM  teachers
CROSS JOIN students
LEFT JOIN Table1 t
  ON teachers."TEACHER_ID" = t."TEACHER_ID" 
 AND students."STUDENT_ID"  = t."STUDENT_ID"
 WHERE t."TEACHER_ID" IS NULL
ORDER BY 2, 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by generating *all* combinations of teacher and student using `cross join`.  Then filter out the ones that exist:

```
select t.teacher_id, s.student_id
from (select distinct teacher_id from t) t cross join
     (select distinct student_id from t) s
minus
select t.teacher_id, s.student_id
from t;
```

For the filtering part, you can also use `not in`, `not exists`, or `left join`/`where`.